# Strange symbols in Firefox address bar with https

Tags: tls, firefox

Why are there dash marks through the https portion of this address?  Is this a feature that's supposed to further accentuate that this is unsecured https?  I just thought it was a graphical glitch because I have never seen these kinds of dash marks through any other site that I have accessed over https whether the cert is self-signed or issued through a CA.

[image: Strange dashes in Firefox address bar]

Additionally, selecting the address in the address bar causes the dashes to go away for as long as the address is selected:

[image: Hidden dashes when address is selected]

I am using Firefox ESR 45.1.1 in case that matters.

Comment: To be honest, looks like a rendering glitch to me, but I don't feel like booting a Windows VM to check. Maybe try out some test bad certificates and see if you can reproduce?: https://badssl.com/

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Hmm, [https://mixed-script.badssl.com/](https://mixed-script.badssl.com/) reproduces it, as does [https://very.badssl.com/](https://very.badssl.com/) but many of the others do not, so it might only occur for mixed-content sites.

Comment: Odd, you've convinced me to try it in a VM, but I can't reproduce it. Windows 7 Firefox ESR 45.1.1 (32 and 64 bit FF the same). Extension related maybe?

Comment: Wait, my icon looks different from your new screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvgtx.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the connection is insecure due to mixed content, and you've disabled mixed content blocking, the strike through is supposed to be solid line over the https scheme name:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure))</sub>

That yours show up as broken lines is probably a graphical glitch.